# Export Nested JSON to CSV using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested

I have the following JSON script which i got from Xero.
It is a nested JSON script and im trying to create a flat table and then export it to CSV.

I have written this python code but im struggling to flatten the nested JSON script. 
Initially i get the the data from Xero and i use the **json.dumps** so as to serialise the datetime. The JSON export which is displayed here comes from Postman software. When i get the JSON script using python the date format is the following **'UpdatedDateUTC': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 24, 12, 53, 55, 930000)**. So i use **json.dumps** so as to serialise it.

When i produce the first export:

```
df = pd.read_json(b_str)
df.to_csv(path+'invoices.csv')
```

The CSV file looks like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The next step is to flatten the **Contact** and **CreditNotes** columns and make them part of the main table. So instead of the **Contact** column will have 8 new columns: **ContactID, ContactNumber, Name, Addresses, Phones, ContactGroups, ContactPersons, HasValidationErrors**. Similar process for CreditNotes column

Im trying to replicate the methodology on this [link](https://mindtrove.info/flatten-nested-json-with-pandas/) but with no luck. I get an export which looks like this. The contacts_with_id dataframe is shown on multiple rows and not multiple columns. I cant figure out what i am doing wrong.

[image]

I have also used the flatten_json function but with no luck either.

I dont really need to make this methodology work. I just want to find a way to export the nested json script to a readable csv file.

---

Python Code:

```
from xero import Xero
from xero.auth import PrivateCredentials
with open("E:\\privatekey.pem") as keyfile:
    rsa_key = keyfile.read()
credentials = PrivateCredentials('BHK1ZBEKIL4WM0BLKLIOT65PSIA43N', rsa_key)
xero = Xero(credentials)

import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize #package for flattening json in pandas df

# The following is a list
a_list = xero.invoices.all()

# The following is a string. Serialised Datetime
b_str = json.dumps(a_list, default=str)

path='E:\\MyDrive\\Python Workspaces\\'
df = pd.read_json(b_str)
df.to_csv(path+'invoices.csv')

# ********************* FLATTEN JSON *****************

dd = json.loads(b_str)

contacts_with_id = pd.io.json.json_normalize(dd, record_path='Contact', meta='InvoiceID',
                                    record_prefix='Contact.')

df_final = pd.merge(contacts_with_id, df, how='inner', on='InvoiceID')
df_final.to_csv(path+'invoices_final.csv')
```

---

Json Script Below:

```
{
"Id": "568d1686-7c53-4f22-a93f-754589a246a7",
"Status": "OK",
"ProviderName": "Rest API",
"DateTimeUTC": "/Date(1552234854959)/",
"Invoices": [
    {
        "Type": "ACCPAY",
        "InvoiceID": "8289ab9d-2134-4601-8622-e7fdae4b6d89",
        "InvoiceNumber": "10522",
        "Reference": "10522",
        "Payments": [],
        "CreditNotes": [],
        "Prepayments": [],
        "Overpayments": [],
        "AmountDue": 102,
        "AmountPaid": 0,
        "AmountCredited": 0,
        "CurrencyRate": 1,
        "HasErrors": false,
        "IsDiscounted": false,
        "HasAttachments": false,
        "Contact": {
            "ContactID": "d1dba397-0f0b-4819-a6ce-2839b7be5008",
            "ContactNumber": "c03bbcb5-fb0b-4f46-83f0-8687f754488b",
            "Name": "Micro",
            "Addresses": [],
            "Phones": [],
            "ContactGroups": [],
            "ContactPersons": [],
            "HasValidationErrors": false
        },
        "DateString": "2017-02-06T00:00:00",
        "Date": "/Date(1486339200000+0000)/",
        "DueDateString": "2017-03-08T00:00:00",
        "DueDate": "/Date(1488931200000+0000)/",
        "Status": "AUTHORISED",
        "LineAmountTypes": "Exclusive",
        "LineItems": [],
        "SubTotal": 85,
        "TotalTax": 17,
        "Total": 102,
        "UpdatedDateUTC": "/Date(1529940362110+0000)/",
        "CurrencyCode": "GBP"
    },
    {
        "Type": "ACCREC",
        "InvoiceID": "9e37150f-88a5-4213-a085-b30c5e01c2bf",
        "InvoiceNumber": "(13)",
        "Reference": "",
        "Payments": [],
        "CreditNotes": [
            {
                "CreditNoteID": "3c5c7dec-534a-46e0-ad1b-f0f69822cfd5",
                "CreditNoteNumber": "(12)",
                "ID": "3c5c7dec-534a-46e0-ad1b-f0f69822cfd5",
                "AppliedAmount": 1200,
                "DateString": "2011-05-04T00:00:00",
                "Date": "/Date(1304467200000+0000)/",
                "LineItems": [],
                "Total": 7800
            },
            {
                "CreditNoteID": "af38e37f-4ba3-4208-a193-a32b418c2bbc",
                "CreditNoteNumber": "(14)",
                "ID": "af38e37f-4ba3-4208-a193-a32b418c2bbc",
                "AppliedAmount": 2600,
                "DateString": "2011-05-04T00:00:00",
                "Date": "/Date(1304467200000+0000)/",
                "LineItems": [],
                "Total": 2600
            }
        ],
        "Prepayments": [],
        "Overpayments": [],
        "AmountDue": 0,
        "AmountPaid": 0,
        "AmountCredited": 3800,
        "CurrencyRate": 1,
        "HasErrors": false,
        "IsDiscounted": false,
        "HasAttachments": false,
        "Contact": {
            "ContactID": "58164bd6-5225-4f30-ad89-35140db5b624",
            "ContactNumber": "d0b420b8-4a58-40d1-9717-8525edda7658",
            "Name": "FSales (1)",
            "Addresses": [],
            "Phones": [],
            "ContactGroups": [],
            "ContactPersons": [],
            "HasValidationErrors": false
        },
        "DateString": "2011-05-04T00:00:00",
        "Date": "/Date(1304467200000+0000)/",
        "DueDateString": "2011-06-03T00:00:00",
        "DueDate": "/Date(1307059200000+0000)/",
        "Status": "PAID",
        "LineAmountTypes": "Exclusive",
        "LineItems": [],
        "SubTotal": 3166.67,
        "TotalTax": 633.33,
        "Total": 3800,
        "UpdatedDateUTC": "/Date(1529943661150+0000)/",
        "CurrencyCode": "GBP",
        "FullyPaidOnDate": "/Date(1304467200000+0000)/"
    },
    {
        "Type": "ACCPAY",
        "InvoiceID": "1ddea7ec-a0d5-457a-a8fd-cfcdc2099d51",
        "InvoiceNumber": "01596057543",
        "Reference": "",
        "Payments": [
            {
                "PaymentID": "fd639da3-c009-47df-a4bf-98ccd5c68e43",
                "Date": "/Date(1551657600000+0000)/",
                "Amount": 173.86,
                "Reference": "",
                "CurrencyRate": 1,
                "HasAccount": false,
                "HasValidationErrors": false
            }
        ],
        "CreditNotes": [],
        "Prepayments": [],
        "Overpayments": [],
        "AmountDue": 0,
        "AmountPaid": 173.86,
        "AmountCredited": 0,
        "CurrencyRate": 1,
        "HasErrors": false,
        "IsDiscounted": false,
        "HasAttachments": true,
        "Contact": {
            "ContactID": "309afb74-0a3b-4d68-85e8-2259ca5acd13",
            "ContactNumber": "91eef1f0-5fe6-45d7-b739-1ab5352a5523",
            "Name": "Company AAA",
            "Addresses": [],
            "Phones": [],
            "ContactGroups": [],
            "ContactPersons": [],
            "HasValidationErrors": false
        },
        "DateString": "2019-02-23T00:00:00",
        "Date": "/Date(1550880000000+0000)/",
        "DueDateString": "2019-03-21T00:00:00",
        "DueDate": "/Date(1553126400000+0000)/",
        "Status": "PAID",
        "LineAmountTypes": "Exclusive",
        "LineItems": [],
        "SubTotal": 144.88,
        "TotalTax": 28.98,
        "Total": 173.86,
        "UpdatedDateUTC": "/Date(1551777481907+0000)/",
        "CurrencyCode": "GBP",
        "FullyPaidOnDate": "/Date(1551657600000+0000)/"
    },
    {
        "Type": "ACCPAY",
        "InvoiceID": "ba5ff3b1-1058-4645-80da-5475c23da949",
        "InvoiceNumber": "Q0603",
        "Reference": "",
        "Payments": [],
        "CreditNotes": [],
        "Prepayments": [],
        "Overpayments": [],
        "AmountDue": 213.24,
        "AmountPaid": 0,
        "AmountCredited": 0,
        "CurrencyRate": 1,
        "HasErrors": false,
        "IsDiscounted": false,
        "HasAttachments": true,
        "Contact": {
            "ContactID": "f0473b41-da92-4397-9d2c-741812f2475c",
            "ContactNumber": "1f124969-de8d-40b8-8140-d4997511b0dc",
            "Name": "BTelcom",
            "Addresses": [],
            "Phones": [],
            "ContactGroups": [],
            "ContactPersons": [],
            "HasValidationErrors": false
        },
        "DateString": "2019-03-05T00:00:00",
        "Date": "/Date(1551744000000+0000)/",
        "DueDateString": "2019-03-21T00:00:00",
        "DueDate": "/Date(1553126400000+0000)/",
        "Status": "SUBMITTED",
        "LineAmountTypes": "Exclusive",
        "LineItems": [],
        "SubTotal": 177.7,
        "TotalTax": 35.54,
        "Total": 213.24,
        "UpdatedDateUTC": "/Date(1552068778417+0000)/",
        "CurrencyCode": "GBP"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something like this before:

Basically flattened out the entire nested json, then iterate through those columns (which uses a pattern to include which row it would be constructed into a table) to create the new rows.

There are 4 invoices, and this creates 4 rows (for each of the invoices). Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

***NOTE*** Where you might run into some issues:

One of the things to consider if trying to flatten out a json file where there is nested lists, and the nested lists are of different lengths, anytime a single row has ONE value for any given column, it has to create that column even if all the other rows are null. In that `Payments` Key, there are lists with additional 7 elements. So if there are 8 payments for some IDs (as opposed to all the others only having 1 payment), it'll have to create 56 additional columns to store all those in separate columns / flat file.

```
jsonStr = '''{
"Id": "568d1686-7c53-4f22-a93f-754589a246a7",
"Status": "OK",
"ProviderName": "Rest API",
"DateTimeUTC": "/Date(1552234854959)/",
"Invoices": [
    {
        "Type": "ACCPAY",
        "InvoiceID": "8289ab9d-2134-4601-8622-e7fdae4b6d89",
        "InvoiceNumber": "10522",
        "Reference": "10522",
        "Payments": [],
        "CreditNotes": [],
        "Prepayments": [],
        "Overpayments": [],
        "AmountDue": 102,
        "AmountPaid": 0,
        "AmountCredited": 0,
        "CurrencyRate": 1,
        "HasErrors": false,
        "IsDiscounted": false,
        "HasAttachments": false,
        "Contact": {
            "ContactID": "d1dba397-0f0b-4819-a6ce-2839b7be5008",
            "ContactNumber": "c03bbcb5-fb0b-4f46-83f0-8687f754488b",
            "Name": "Micro",
            "Addresses": [],
            "Phones": [],
            "ContactGroups": [],
            "ContactPersons": [],
            "HasValidationErrors": false
        },
        "DateString": "2017-02-06T00:00:00",
        "Date": "/Date(1486339200000+0000)/",
        "DueDateString": "2017-03-08T00:00:00",
        "DueDate": "/Date(1488931200000+0000)/",
        "Status": "AUTHORISED",
        "LineAmountTypes": "Exclusive",
        "LineItems": [],
        "SubTotal": 85,
        "TotalTax": 17,
        "Total": 102,
        "UpdatedDateUTC": "/Date(1529940362110+0000)/",
        "CurrencyCode": "GBP"
    },
    {
        "Type": "ACCREC",
        "InvoiceID": "9e37150f-88a5-4213-a085-b30c5e01c2bf",
        "InvoiceNumber": "(13)",
        "Reference": "",
        "Payments": [],
        "CreditNotes": [
            {
                "CreditNoteID": "3c5c7dec-534a-46e0-ad1b-f0f69822cfd5",
                "CreditNoteNumber": "(12)",
                "ID": "3c5c7dec-534a-46e0-ad1b-f0f69822cfd5",
                "AppliedAmount": 1200,
                "DateString": "2011-05-04T00:00:00",
                "Date": "/Date(1304467200000+0000)/",
                "LineItems": [],
                "Total": 7800
            },
            {
                "CreditNoteID": "af38e37f-4ba3-4208-a193-a32b418c2bbc",
                "CreditNoteNumber": "(14)",
                "ID": "af38e37f-4ba3-4208-a193-a32b418c2bbc",
                "AppliedAmount": 2600,
                "DateString": "2011-05-04T00:00:00",
                "Date": "/Date(1304467200000+0000)/",
                "LineItems": [],
                "Total": 2600
            }
        ],
        "Prepayments": [],
        "Overpayments": [],
        "AmountDue": 0,
        "AmountPaid": 0,
        "AmountCredited": 3800,
        "CurrencyRate": 1,
        "HasErrors": false,
        "IsDiscounted": false,
        "HasAttachments": false,
        "Contact": {
            "ContactID": "58164bd6-5225-4f30-ad89-35140db5b624",
            "ContactNumber": "d0b420b8-4a58-40d1-9717-8525edda7658",
            "Name": "FSales (1)",
            "Addresses": [],
            "Phones": [],
            "ContactGroups": [],
            "ContactPersons": [],
            "HasValidationErrors": false
        },
        "DateString": "2011-05-04T00:00:00",
        "Date": "/Date(1304467200000+0000)/",
        "DueDateString": "2011-06-03T00:00:00",
        "DueDate": "/Date(1307059200000+0000)/",
        "Status": "PAID",
        "LineAmountTypes": "Exclusive",
        "LineItems": [],
        "SubTotal": 3166.67,
        "TotalTax": 633.33,
        "Total": 3800,
        "UpdatedDateUTC": "/Date(1529943661150+0000)/",
        "CurrencyCode": "GBP",
        "FullyPaidOnDate": "/Date(1304467200000+0000)/"
    },
    {
        "Type": "ACCPAY",
        "InvoiceID": "1ddea7ec-a0d5-457a-a8fd-cfcdc2099d51",
        "InvoiceNumber": "01596057543",
        "Reference": "",
        "Payments": [
            {
                "PaymentID": "fd639da3-c009-47df-a4bf-98ccd5c68e43",
                "Date": "/Date(1551657600000+0000)/",
                "Amount": 173.86,
                "Reference": "",
                "CurrencyRate": 1,
                "HasAccount": false,
                "HasValidationErrors": false
            }
        ],
        "CreditNotes": [],
        "Prepayments": [],
        "Overpayments": [],
        "AmountDue": 0,
        "AmountPaid": 173.86,
        "AmountCredited": 0,
        "CurrencyRate": 1,
        "HasErrors": false,
        "IsDiscounted": false,
        "HasAttachments": true,
        "Contact": {
            "ContactID": "309afb74-0a3b-4d68-85e8-2259ca5acd13",
            "ContactNumber": "91eef1f0-5fe6-45d7-b739-1ab5352a5523",
            "Name": "Company AAA",
            "Addresses": [],
            "Phones": [],
            "ContactGroups": [],
            "ContactPersons": [],
            "HasValidationErrors": false
        },
        "DateString": "2019-02-23T00:00:00",
        "Date": "/Date(1550880000000+0000)/",
        "DueDateString": "2019-03-21T00:00:00",
        "DueDate": "/Date(1553126400000+0000)/",
        "Status": "PAID",
        "LineAmountTypes": "Exclusive",
        "LineItems": [],
        "SubTotal": 144.88,
        "TotalTax": 28.98,
        "Total": 173.86,
        "UpdatedDateUTC": "/Date(1551777481907+0000)/",
        "CurrencyCode": "GBP",
        "FullyPaidOnDate": "/Date(1551657600000+0000)/"
    },
    {
        "Type": "ACCPAY",
        "InvoiceID": "ba5ff3b1-1058-4645-80da-5475c23da949",
        "InvoiceNumber": "Q0603",
        "Reference": "",
        "Payments": [],
        "CreditNotes": [],
        "Prepayments": [],
        "Overpayments": [],
        "AmountDue": 213.24,
        "AmountPaid": 0,
        "AmountCredited": 0,
        "CurrencyRate": 1,
        "HasErrors": false,
        "IsDiscounted": false,
        "HasAttachments": true,
        "Contact": {
            "ContactID": "f0473b41-da92-4397-9d2c-741812f2475c",
            "ContactNumber": "1f124969-de8d-40b8-8140-d4997511b0dc",
            "Name": "BTelcom",
            "Addresses": [],
            "Phones": [],
            "ContactGroups": [],
            "ContactPersons": [],
            "HasValidationErrors": false
        },
        "DateString": "2019-03-05T00:00:00",
        "Date": "/Date(1551744000000+0000)/",
        "DueDateString": "2019-03-21T00:00:00",
        "DueDate": "/Date(1553126400000+0000)/",
        "Status": "SUBMITTED",
        "LineAmountTypes": "Exclusive",
        "LineItems": [],
        "SubTotal": 177.7,
        "TotalTax": 35.54,
        "Total": 213.24,
        "UpdatedDateUTC": "/Date(1552068778417+0000)/",
        "CurrencyCode": "GBP"
    }
]
}'''



import json
import pandas as pd
import re

def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(y)
    return out

jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)
flat = flatten_json(jsonObj)

results = pd.DataFrame()
special_cols = []

columns_list = list(flat.keys())
for item in columns_list:
    try:
        row_idx = re.findall(r'\_(\d+)\_', item )[0]
    except:
        special_cols.append(item)
        continue
    column = re.findall(r'\_\d+\_(.*)', item )[0]
    column = column.replace('_', '')

    row_idx = int(row_idx)
    value = flat[item]

    results.loc[row_idx, column] = value

for item in special_cols:
    results[item] = flat[item]
```

**Output:**

```
print (results.to_string())
     Type                             InvoiceID InvoiceNumber Reference  AmountDue  AmountPaid  AmountCredited  CurrencyRate  HasErrors  IsDiscounted  HasAttachments                      ContactContactID                  ContactContactNumber  ContactName  ContactHasValidationErrors           DateString                        Date        DueDateString                     DueDate Status LineAmountTypes  SubTotal  TotalTax    Total              UpdatedDateUTC CurrencyCode              CreditNotes0CreditNoteID CreditNotes0CreditNoteNumber                        CreditNotes0ID  CreditNotes0AppliedAmount CreditNotes0DateString            CreditNotes0Date  CreditNotes0Total              CreditNotes1CreditNoteID CreditNotes1CreditNoteNumber                        CreditNotes1ID  CreditNotes1AppliedAmount CreditNotes1DateString            CreditNotes1Date  CreditNotes1Total             FullyPaidOnDate                    Payments0PaymentID               Payments0Date  Payments0Amount Payments0Reference  Payments0CurrencyRate Payments0HasAccount Payments0HasValidationErrors                                    Id ProviderName            DateTimeUTC
0  ACCPAY  8289ab9d-2134-4601-8622-e7fdae4b6d89         10522     10522     102.00        0.00             0.0           1.0      False         False           False  d1dba397-0f0b-4819-a6ce-2839b7be5008  c03bbcb5-fb0b-4f46-83f0-8687f754488b        Micro                       False  2017-02-06T00:00:00  /Date(1486339200000+0000)/  2017-03-08T00:00:00  /Date(1488931200000+0000)/     OK       Exclusive     85.00     17.00   102.00  /Date(1529940362110+0000)/          GBP                                   NaN                          NaN                                   NaN                        NaN                    NaN                         NaN                NaN                                   NaN                          NaN                                   NaN                        NaN                    NaN                         NaN                NaN                         NaN                                   NaN                         NaN              NaN                NaN                    NaN                 NaN                          NaN  568d1686-7c53-4f22-a93f-754589a246a7     Rest API  /Date(1552234854959)/
1  ACCREC  9e37150f-88a5-4213-a085-b30c5e01c2bf          (13)                 0.00        0.00          3800.0           1.0      False         False           False  58164bd6-5225-4f30-ad89-35140db5b624  d0b420b8-4a58-40d1-9717-8525edda7658   FSales (1)                       False  2011-05-04T00:00:00  /Date(1304467200000+0000)/  2011-06-03T00:00:00  /Date(1307059200000+0000)/     OK       Exclusive   3166.67    633.33  3800.00  /Date(1529943661150+0000)/          GBP  3c5c7dec-534a-46e0-ad1b-f0f69822cfd5                         (12)  3c5c7dec-534a-46e0-ad1b-f0f69822cfd5                     1200.0    2011-05-04T00:00:00  /Date(1304467200000+0000)/             7800.0  af38e37f-4ba3-4208-a193-a32b418c2bbc                         (14)  af38e37f-4ba3-4208-a193-a32b418c2bbc                     2600.0    2011-05-04T00:00:00  /Date(1304467200000+0000)/             2600.0  /Date(1304467200000+0000)/                                   NaN                         NaN              NaN                NaN                    NaN                 NaN                          NaN  568d1686-7c53-4f22-a93f-754589a246a7     Rest API  /Date(1552234854959)/
2  ACCPAY  1ddea7ec-a0d5-457a-a8fd-cfcdc2099d51   01596057543                 0.00      173.86             0.0           1.0      False         False            True  309afb74-0a3b-4d68-85e8-2259ca5acd13  91eef1f0-5fe6-45d7-b739-1ab5352a5523  Company AAA                       False  2019-02-23T00:00:00  /Date(1550880000000+0000)/  2019-03-21T00:00:00  /Date(1553126400000+0000)/     OK       Exclusive    144.88     28.98   173.86  /Date(1551777481907+0000)/          GBP                                   NaN                          NaN                                   NaN                        NaN                    NaN                         NaN                NaN                                   NaN                          NaN                                   NaN                        NaN                    NaN                         NaN                NaN  /Date(1551657600000+0000)/  fd639da3-c009-47df-a4bf-98ccd5c68e43  /Date(1551657600000+0000)/           173.86                                       1.0               False                        False  568d1686-7c53-4f22-a93f-754589a246a7     Rest API  /Date(1552234854959)/
3  ACCPAY  ba5ff3b1-1058-4645-80da-5475c23da949         Q0603               213.24        0.00             0.0           1.0      False         False            True  f0473b41-da92-4397-9d2c-741812f2475c  1f124969-de8d-40b8-8140-d4997511b0dc      BTelcom                       False  2019-03-05T00:00:00  /Date(1551744000000+0000)/  2019-03-21T00:00:00  /Date(1553126400000+0000)/     OK       Exclusive    177.70     35.54   213.24  /Date(1552068778417+0000)/          GBP                                   NaN                          NaN                                   NaN                        NaN                    NaN                         NaN                NaN                                   NaN                          NaN                                   NaN                        NaN                    NaN                         NaN                NaN                         NaN                                   NaN                         NaN              NaN                NaN                    NaN                 NaN                          NaN  568d1686-7c53-4f22-a93f-754589a246a7     Rest API  /Date(1552234854959)/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply @chitown88. Very close to my needs. When i run it for the whole JSON file i only get 15 rows and the output consumes all the available columns of Excel and it says 'File not Loaded Successfully'. I get the output from this statement:  **b_str = json.dumps(a_list, default=str)** . Any ideas why this is happening. Is it the json.dumps that changes the initial format of the json?